# Unicode version of ClipboardAsString

Tags: delphi, unicode

I've been using Peter Below's APIClipboard unit for many years, but it no longer works under Unicode Delphi.

**ClipboardAsString returns gobbledegook:**

```
Procedure DataFromClipboard( fmt: DWORD; S: TStream );
  Var
    hMem: THandle;
    pMem: Pointer;
    datasize: DWORD;
  Begin { DataFromClipboard }
    Assert( Assigned( S ));
    hMem := GetClipboardData( fmt );
    If hMem <> 0 Then Begin
      datasize := GlobalSize( hMem );
      If datasize > 0 Then Begin
        pMem := GlobalLock( hMem );
        If pMem = Nil Then
          raise EclipboardError.Create( eLockFailed );
        try
          S.WriteBuffer( pMem^, datasize );
        finally
          GlobalUnlock( hMem );
        end;
      End;
    End;
  End;



Procedure CopyDataFromClipboard( fmt: DWORD; S: TStream );
  Begin { CopyDataFromClipboard }
    Assert( Assigned( S ));
    If OpenClipboard( 0 ) Then
      try
        DataFromClipboard( fmt , S );
      finally
        CloseClipboard;
      end
    Else
      raise EclipboardError.Create( eCannotOpenClipboard );
  End; 


Function ClipboardAsString: String;
  Const
    nullchar: Char = #0;
  Var
    ms: TMemoryStream;
  Begin { ClipboardAsString }
    If not IsClipboardFormatAvailable( CF_TEXT ) Then
      Result := EmptyStr
    Else Begin
      ms:= TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        CopyDataFromClipboard( CF_TEXT , ms );
        ms.Seek( 0, soFromEnd );
        ms.WriteBuffer( nullChar, Sizeof( nullchar ));
        Result := Pchar( ms.Memory );
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
    End;
  End;
```

And StringToClipboard copies only the first character:

```
Procedure DataToClipboard( fmt: DWORD; Const data; datasize: Integer );
  Var
    hMem: THandle;
    pMem: Pointer;
  Begin { DataToClipboard }
    If datasize <= 0 Then Exit;
    hMem := GlobalAlloc( GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_SHARE or GMEM_ZEROINIT ,
                         datasize );
    If hmem = 0 Then
      raise EclipboardError.Create( eSystemOutOfMemory );

    pMem := GlobalLock( hMem );
    If pMem = Nil Then Begin
      GlobalFree( hMem );
      raise EclipboardError.Create( eLockFailed );
    End;

    Move( data, pMem^, datasize );
    GlobalUnlock( hMem );
    If SetClipboardData( fmt, hMem ) = 0 Then
      raise EClipboarderror( eSetDataFailed );
  End; { DataToClipboard }

Procedure CopyDataToClipboard( fmt: DWORD; Const data; datasize: 
Integer;
                               emptyClipboardFirst: Boolean = true );
  Begin { CopyDataToClipboard }
    If OpenClipboard( 0 ) Then
      try
        If emptyClipboardFirst Then
          EmptyClipboard;
        DataToClipboard( fmt, data, datasize );
      finally
        CloseClipboard;
      end
    Else
      raise EclipboardError.Create( eCannotOpenClipboard );
  End; 

Procedure StringToClipboard( Const S: String );
  Begin
    If Length(S) > 0 Then
      CopyDataToClipboard( CF_TEXT, S[1], Length(S)+1);
  End;
```

I have searched but cannot find an updated version of this unit. Does anyone with more experience with Unicode strings know the best way to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does replacing all instances of `pchar/string` to `pansichar/ansistring` not do the trick?

Comment: Why don't you use `Clipboard.AsText := S` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CF_TEXT` is Ansi, `CF_UNICODETEXT` is Unicode. The code needs to be updated to use the appropriate format based on whether `string` is Ansi or Unicode, eg:

```
Const
  CFTextFmt = {$IFDEF UNICODE}CF_UNICODETEXT{$ELSE}CF_TEXT{$ENDIF};

Function ClipboardAsString: String;
  Var
    ms: TMemoryStream;
  Begin { ClipboardAsString }
    If not IsClipboardFormatAvailable( CFTextFmt ) Then
      Result := EmptyStr
    Else Begin
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        CopyDataFromClipboard( CFTextFmt, ms );
        SetString(Result, PChar(ms.Memory), ms.Size);
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
    End;
  End; 

Procedure StringToClipboard( Const S: String );
  Begin
    CopyDataToClipboard( CFTextFmt, PChar(S)^, (Length(S) + 1) * SizeOf(Char));
  End;
```

Or, you could just use the VCL's own `TClipboard.AsText` property instead, which handles these details for you:

```
uses
  Clipbrd;

Function ClipboardAsString: String;
  Begin
    Result := Clipboard.AsText;
  End; 

Procedure StringToClipboard( Const S: String );
  Begin
    Clipboard.AsText := S;
  End;
```

With that said, on a side note, `DataToClipboard()` has some bugs in it.  It should allow `datasize` to be 0 and not ignore it, otherwise it is not possible to store blank data (which is something desirable).  It does not need to use `GMEM_ZEROINIT` (not a bug, but is wasted overhead).  And it needs to free the `HGLOBAL` if `SetClipboardData()` fails:

```
Procedure DataToClipboard( fmt: DWORD; Const data; datasize: Integer );
  Var
    hMem: THandle;
    pMem: Pointer;
  Begin { DataToClipboard }
    If datasize < 0 Then datasize := 0;
    hMem := GlobalAlloc( GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_SHARE, datasize );
    If hMem = 0 Then
      raise EclipboardError.Create( eSystemOutOfMemory );
    Try
      If datasize > 0 Then 
      Begin
        pMem := GlobalLock( hMem );
        If pMem = Nil Then
          raise EclipboardError.Create( eLockFailed );
        Try
          Move( data, pMem^, datasize );
        Finally
          GlobalUnlock( hMem );
        End;
      End;
      If SetClipboardData( fmt, hMem ) = 0 Then
        raise EClipboarderror( eSetDataFailed );
    Except
      GlobalFree( hMem );
      raise;
    End;
  End; { DataToClipboard }
```

There is also a bug in `CopyDataToClipboard()` when `emptyClipboardFirst` is True:

> If an application calls OpenClipboard with hwnd set to NULL, EmptyClipboard sets the clipboard owner to NULL; **this causes SetClipboardData to fail**.

So, you must pass a valid non-zero `HWND` to `OpenClipboard()` when emptying the clipboard and then putting new data on it.